Question about Power Automate (flow) contains expression
Edit
Managed to solve it by changing the mailUser string into an object.
I have a very simple flow which triggers upon receiving an email. In the next steps the details of the mail will be extracted and the email of the sender will be stored in a variable called mailUser.
In the next step I want to check if the email of the sender is already stored in one of my Sharepoint Lists. In order to do so, the flow will get all of the data from the sharepoint list and will store the desired column "email" in a variable array named userArray.
Both variables seem to work and provide me with the data shown below:
mailUser
testing@gmail.com

userArray
[
  {
    "Email": "testing@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "Email": "testing@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "Email": "testing@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "Email": "testing@gmail.com"
  }
]

The sharepoint list only contains the test email (4x)
Condition
In order to comparee the two values, I added a condition with the "contains" expression. However, it always seems to result FALSE.



userArray is an array of objects where the Email field is the email address you want.  So you need to make such an object with mailUser and see if that is contained in the array.  Or you can change the array to be of just email addresses.

Thank you for your comment @ScottHunter
I have no idea how to do that.. I tried many things to manipulate "mailUser" and "userArray", but nothing seems to work..

You could loop over the elements of userArray, test each value individually, and set some variable if any match.

Ah, thank you for your reply but I managed to turn the mailUser string into an object and it seems to work. :D
